# Unpack nodes of a dict for each slash in the key

Tags: python, firebase

I have a dict:

```
a = {
  "group_a/category_a/metric_a": 5,
  "group_a/category_a/metric_b": 4,
  "group_a/category_b/metric_a": 3,
  "group_a/category_b/metric_b": 2,
  "group_b/category_a/metric_d": 1
}
```

I would like to unpack the nodes by creating a nested view, seperated by each slash, where the outcome looks as follows:

```
b = {
  "group_a": {
        "category_a": {
            "metric_a": 5,
            "metric_b": 4
        },
        "category_b": {
            "metric_a": 3,
            "metric_b": 2
        },
   "group_b": {
        "category_a": {
            "metric_d": 1
        }
    }
}
```

How can we go from a to b? I encountered this problem when trying to publish the dict above to Firebase as the nodes `group_a/category_a/metric_a` is not accepted, whereas a dict that is nested is allowed.

Comment: What is your current inefficient solution?

Comment: I actually don't know where to start, as doing a for loop would not be probably the best idea. Maybe this is a common problem and there is already a built in function. I encountered the issue when trying to post to Firebase, where such keys where not accepted.

Comment: @Sayse I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63830988/4262057

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through, split each key into a list of keys, create sub-dictionaries as required...

```
from pprint import pprint

a = {
  "group_a/category_a/metric_a": 5,
  "group_a/category_a/metric_b": 4,
  "group_a/category_b/metric_a": 3,
  "group_a/category_b/metric_b": 2,
  "group_b/category_a/metric_d": 1
}

b = {}
for k, v in a.items():
    dct = b
    keys = k.split("/")
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        if key not in dct:
            dct[key] = {}
        dct = dct[key]
    dct[keys[-1]] = v

pprint(b)
```

Gives:

```
{'group_a': {'category_a': {'metric_a': 5, 'metric_b': 4},
             'category_b': {'metric_a': 3, 'metric_b': 2}},
 'group_b': {'category_a': {'metric_d': 1}}}
```

Comment: Does this account for "recursiveness" of when the number of slashes changes to 4 instead of 3 like this in example?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question here, but after tokenising the key it will loop through all but the last element creating parent dictionaries if they don't already exist, and then it will use the last element as the key to actually create with the specified value.  You can see that no particular depth is assumed -- and the depth doesn't have to be the same for all of them.

Comment: Got it, yes it seems to work. Thank you for the contribution, despite the many negative down comments on my question.